# Difficulties with texstudio and texlive

Tags: texlive, glossaries, texstudio

I usually use an online latex compiler, like overleaf, but I need to be able to write on latex files offline too.

I am on ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to use texlive along with texstudio but I am having difficulties.

When I try to build a document texstudio returns

> File `glossaries.sty' not found. ^^M

I tried to figure out which version of texlive I need by

```
morten@mortenThinkPad:~$ apt-file search glossaries.sty
texlive-lang-arabic: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/simurgh/simurgh-glossaries.sty
texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/testidx/testidx-glossaries.sty
texlive-latex-recommended: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-glossaries.sty
```

But when I try t install `texlive-latex-recommended` it says it's already installed

```
morten@mortenThinkPad:~$ sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-latex-recommended is already the newest version (2017.20180305-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have also checked the texstudio path, `which latex` in the terminal returns `/usr/bin/latex` which I wrote into the texstudio path[image]

I am not terribly experienced with local latex compilers so I am not terribly sure what to do.

Comment: Did you also install `texlive-latex-extra`? The actual `glossaries` package is in there (`/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty`). You can also install `texlive-full` to get all packages at once, however that takes a lot of disk space (several GB).

Comment: You were absolutely correct. Thank you